# iPad UIPopoverController with buttons, same as Contacts App

Tags: ipad, ios, uipopovercontroller

I would like to create a PopoverController containing buttons, like this one:

[image]

I can create a UIViewController containing two buttons, but they won't be identical to those shown on screenshot above

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a `UIActionSheet`.

On the iPad the `UIActionSheet` class presents itself as a popover view  when given a particular rect to present from. Without the given rect, it will display in the centre of the screen similar to a `UIAlertView`.